# Arithmetic Overflow error converting varchar to numeric when using IsNumeric in SQL

Tags: sql-server

When I try to insert into a temporary table a decimal, I get an arithmetic overflow error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

This is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #ObDiabetesEncounterIDs
(
     PatientEncounterID int, 
     Value decimal(5,2)
)

INSERT INTO #ObDiabetesEncounterIDs(PatientEncounterID, Value)
    SELECT PatientEncounterID, Value 
    FROM Observation 
    WHERE Term = 'HGBA1C' 
      AND ISNUMERIC(Value) = 1 
      AND Value IS NOT NULL 
      AND PatientEncounterID IS NOT NULL;
```

Most of the decimal values are between 5.1 to 15.1. There are a few values that are whole numbers like 15 and 10. There are 2 that are out of that range such as 1405 and 151. I thought I accommodated these values by using the data type `decimal(5,2)`.

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**
Updating the precision of the decimal helped.  This accounted for the 1 record that was 1403.  But there is also 1 record that has a comma instead of a period.
So, the value is 9,7.
So, I believe I will need to check for ISNUMERIC then change any commas to periods, then cast as a decimal.

Comment: `DECIMAL(5,2)` has **5 digits** overall, of which **2** are after the decimal point - so you can store values from 0.00 to 999.99 in that type - a value like `1405` **CANNOT** be stored in such a decimal column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Value` is character data, cast it to `DECIMAL` in your `SELECT` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #ObDiabetesEncounterIDs(PatientEncounterID int, Value decimal(7,2));

INSERT INTO #ObDiabetesEncounterIDs(PatientEncounterID, Value)
SELECT PatientEncounterID, CAST(Value AS DECIMAL(7,2))
  FROM Observation 
  WHERE Term = 'HGBA1C' 
    AND Value IS NOT NULL 
    AND PatientEncounterID IS NOT NULL;
```

To test this, I did the following *(Note that in the following example I named the source table `MyObservation` instead of `Observation` so as not to interfere with the original table)*:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyObservation](
    [PatientEncounterID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Term] [varchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyObservation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [PatientEncounterID] ASC
    )WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyObservation]
    (Value, Term)
    Values ('.01', 'HGBA1C')
        ,('.12', 'HGBA1C')
        ,('1.23', 'HGBA1C')
        ,('12.34', 'HGBA1C')
        ,('123.45', 'HGBA1C')
        ,('1234.56', NULL)
        ,('12345.67', 'HGBA1C')
        ,('non-numeric', 'HGBA1C')
        ,('9.98', 'Not HGBA1C')
        ,('123.4958', 'HGBA1C')

CREATE TABLE #ObDiabetesEncounterIDs(
    PatientEncounterID int, Value decimal(7,2)
);

INSERT INTO #ObDiabetesEncounterIDs(PatientEncounterID, Value)
SELECT PatientEncounterID, CAST(Value AS DECIMAL(7,2))
    FROM [dbo].[MyObservation]
    WHERE Term = 'HGBA1C' 
    AND ISNUMERIC(Value) = 1
    AND Value IS NOT NULL 
    AND PatientEncounterID IS NOT NULL;

SELECT * FROM #ObDiabetesEncounterIDs
```

The above worked flawlessly on my SQL Server 2014 system.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: It is still returning an overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.  I even added `ISNUMERIC(Value) = 1` to the query and the error is still happens.  Shouldn't IsNumeric() suppose to return only values in the column that are numeric and can be CAST as a decimal?

Comment: Would you please post at least a partial schema of your Observation table showing the columns `PatientEncounterID` and `Value`?  It also would be worthwhile if you could post a few sample values.

Comment: This answer will work.  The problem with my data is that there was a comma in one of the rows (9,7) and data with a comma and a period (6.,7).  Once I replaced those, it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: I've worked up a full example, above.  There must be an issue with your data.  Find offending records by this query:  `SELECT PatientEncounterId, Value, Term FROM [Observation] WHERE NOT(Term='HGBA1C' AND ISNUMERIC(Value)=1 AND Value IS NOT NULL AND PatientEncounterID IS NOT NULL);`

Answer (score 0):

Your type is wrong.  `decimal(5,2)` is for 3 digits to the right of the decimal and 2 digits to the left.  Try changing that to `decimal(7,2)`.

Comment: I get the error, **Error converting data type varchar to numeric.**  However, the documentation states that the first number is precision and the second is scale.  **decimal[ (p[ ,s] )]**  p (precision)
The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: You may want to modify your strategy such that you could determine what row of input data is offensive to the temp table.  Once you have that information it may help you determine the exact issue. Also, what are the data types of the source table?

Comment: The data type of the source table is a varchar.  The column can hold all types of data.  I thought using `ISNUMERIC() = 1` will only return a number.

Comment: Sorry - didn't realize the input data type.  I'll modify my answer.